# How to query the content of multiple pages in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is this even possible and can anyone give me a simple example? I would like to set up a static page which happens to feature the content of other specific pages in WordPress. The WordPress Codex implies that I can do this somehow with their get_post() function, but all the examples I find deal specifically with *posts* and not *pages*. Is there even a way to use get_post() to get pages? Is this the best method for me to query the content of multiple pages and include it in a single page? Thanks!

Comment: get_post works for pages also.

Comment: *posts* are *pages*, so it should work fine

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure about this. That changes everything for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. It'll give you the content of pages.

```
<?php

    $loop = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'posts_per_page' => any_number_here
        )
    );


    if( $loop->have_posts() ){
        while($loop->have_posts()){
            $loop->the_post();
            echo the_content();
        }
    }
?>
```

`any_number_here` should be a number. So the number of pages you require.
Hope that helps.

Yours,
MMK.